# how to parse json objects from xml in android

Tags: android, xml, json

This is the output from my rest webservice from asp.net. I want to parse. please help..

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"USR_ID":10027,"USR_NAME":"AJAY","ORG_ID":102,"CORPRT_ID":162,"CPRDEPT_ID":16251,"DSGN_CONTROL":"C","DSGTYP_ID":3}]</string>
```

Comment: Thank you... in advance.. :)

Comment: Please google before posting here. I'm sure there are plenty of tutorials out there to help you.

Comment: <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"USR_ID":10027,"USR_NAME":"AJAY","ORG_ID":102,"CORPRT_ID":162,"CPRDEPT_ID":16251,"DSGN_CONTROL":"C","DSGTYP_ID":3}]</string> sorry output is like this